# How to create a frequency histogram in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, histogram, bar-chart, matlab-figure, frequency

I'm trying to plot my data in a histogram. I have 8 ranges, with frequencies of 6, 12, 17, 21, 28, 25, 19, and 15 respectively. However, if I plug these values into an array and run the `histogram` command, I get an image with vertical bars running straight through the top and tons of white space in between.

```
v = [6 12 17 21 28 25 19 15]
histogram(v)
```

If I create a `bar` graph, it works fine but I can't find a way to remove the whitespace between bars. How can I create a histogram with the frequency being the y-axis and each range be labeled on the x-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**`BarWidth`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar-properties.html#property_d0e65960) property of [**`bar`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) to change the separation. Setting to `1` means no separation.

```
bar(v,'BarWidth',1);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [**`Style`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#input_argument_d0e63117) argument to change the style from `grouped` to histogram format using `hist`. i.e.

```
bar(v,'hist');
```

---

For the given data, both of the above approaches give:

[image: output]